# How do I have sorted column names based on a condition?

Tags: database, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, rdbms

I have a table which has the following columns-

- Incident ID (varchar)
- Created Date (varchar- eg- '01-OCT-2014')
- Status (varchar- eg- 'open','closed')

I need to count the incidents based on status and range of dates starting from the created date.

eg.

```
Date Range       || Open          || Closed ||
1-2 days         ||         5     ||       6 ||
2-5 days         ||         4     ||       8 ||
5-15 days        ||         10    ||       15 ||
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: How is the date range calculated? Is it the time from created date to today?

Comment: Yes, Barmar, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(created_date, now()) BETWEEN 1 AND 2
                THEN '1-2 days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(created_date, now()) BETWEEN 3 AND 5
                THEN '3-5 days'
            WHEN DATEDIFF(created_date, now()) BETWEEN 6 AND 15
                THEN '6-15 days'
            ELSE '> 15 days'
        END AS DateRange,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'open' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Open,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'closed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Closed
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY DateRange
```

Comment: It says "missing right parenthesis" at Status = 'open'. Anything I might have missed?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? My answer should work in MySQL.

Comment: Oracle. Sorry if the mysql tag misled you. It was auto suggested when I framed the question.

Comment: I'm not an Oracle user, but I think I've fixed the `SUM` expressions so they'll work in Oracle.

Comment: See https://community.oracle.com/thread/2459688?tstart=0 for how to translate `DATEDIFF` to Oracle.

Comment: Used the whole 'case...' after 'group by' and it worked perfectly. Thanks.